# Can I split a query in multiple queries or create parallelism to speed a query?

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, performance, postgresql

I have a table `avl_pool`, and I have a function to find on the map the link nearest to that `(x, y)` position.

The performance of this select is very linear, the function require ~8 ms to execute. So calculate this select for 1000 rows require 8 seconds. Or as I show in this sample 20.000 rows require 162 seconds.

```
SELECT avl_id, x, y, azimuth, map.get_near_link(X, Y, AZIMUTH)
FROM avl_db.avl_pool         
WHERE avl_id between 1 AND 20000

"Index Scan using avl_pool_pkey on avl_pool  (cost=0.43..11524.76 rows=19143 width=28) (actual time=8.793..162805.384 rows=20000 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: ((avl_id >= 1) AND (avl_id <= 20000))"
"  Buffers: shared hit=19879838"
"Planning time: 0.328 ms"
"Execution time: 162812.113 ms"
```

Using pgAdmin I found out if execute half of the range on separated windows at the same time, the execution time is actually split in half. So looks like the server can handle multiple requests to that same table/function without problem.

```
-- windows 1
SELECT avl_id, x, y, azimuth, map.get_near_link(X, Y, AZIMUTH)
FROM avl_db.avl_pool         
WHERE avl_id between 1 AND 10000 

Total query runtime: 83792 ms.

-- windows 2
SELECT avl_id, x, y, azimuth, map.get_near_link(X, Y, AZIMUTH)
FROM avl_db.avl_pool         
WHERE avl_id between 10001 AND 20000

Total query runtime: 84047 ms.
```

So how should I aproach this scenario to improve performance?.

From the `C#` aproach I guess I can create multiple threads and each one send a portion of the range and then I join all the data in the client. So instead one query with 20k and 162 seconds, I could send 10 querys with 2000 rows and finish in ~16 seconds. Of course maybe there is an overhead cost in the join, but shouldn't be big compared with the 160 seconds.

Or is there is a different aproach I should consider, even better if is a just sql solution?

---

@PeterRing I dont think function code is relevant but anyway here is.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map.get_near_link(
    x NUMERIC,
    y NUMERIC,
    azim NUMERIC)
  RETURNS map.get_near_link AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    strPoint TEXT;
    sRow map.get_near_link;
  BEGIN
    strPoint = 'POINT('|| X || ' ' || Y || ')';
    RAISE DEBUG 'GetLink strPoint % -- Azim %', strPoint, Azim;

    WITH index_query AS (
        SELECT --Seg_ID,
               Link_ID,
               azimuth,
               TRUNC(ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText(strPoint,4326), geom  )*100000)::INTEGER AS distance,
               sentido,
               --ST_AsText(geom),
               geom
        FROM map.vzla_seg S
        WHERE
            ABS(Azim - S.azimuth) < 30 OR
            ABS(Azim - S.azimuth) > 330
        ORDER BY
            geom <-> ST_GeomFromText(strPoint, 4326)
        LIMIT 101
    )
    SELECT i.Link_ID, i.Distance, i.Sentido, v.geom INTO sRow
    FROM
        index_query i INNER JOIN
        map.vzla_rto v ON i.link_id = v.link_id
    ORDER BY
        distance LIMIT 1;

    RAISE DEBUG 'GetLink distance % ', sRow.distance;
    IF sRow.distance > 50 THEN
        sRow.link_id = -1;
    END IF;

    RETURN sRow;
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION map.get_near_link(NUMERIC, NUMERIC, NUMERIC)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Could you show us the map.get_near_link function. 
Also do you need to calculate these link-s every time?

Comment: the time is wall clock time or cpu time?

Comment: Your approach is a reasonable work-around if Postgres can handle the simultaneous query load.  There may be a better approach if you are willing to re-write the UDF.

Comment: If you could write map.get_near_link as a table valued function it will probably help your performance better then any c# tricks.

Comment: @PeterRing I dont think function code is relevant but anyway [**here**](http://pastebin.com/XPnGFH0n) is. Is just select to the map table. I wont calculate same id, after I calculate I will save it to db.

Comment: @Shiping Not sure what you mean? that is the time show in the pgAdmin sql window.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Please can you elaborate? As I try to explain the function is very fast `8ms`, the problem is when you calculate 20k rows .

Comment: @GordonLinoff Im not afraid to rewrite the whole db it if that improve the performance. Right now Im getting 2000 rows / min by the end of the year I expect that be +8000 rows/min so I better found a scalable solution now.

Comment: it takes 8ms, **for every row selected**. If you could write it as a table valued function, and use it in the query as a join, it would execute only once.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I will have to read about `table valued function` not sure why is different? Each row have a different x,y so the function return different value for each row.

Comment: If you save the result in db then why the optimization? Just let it run. Or is the row count so big?

Comment: @PeterRing yes, the problem is the time. Right now I have 2000 row / min so that is  ~8 second, by the end of the year I expect 8000 row / min so at least will need 32 seconds just in that step. So with all the aditional steps there will be a moment where I can't process all data.

Comment: I see what you mean. well, In that case, I might be wrong.

Comment: Usualy this is a very bad idea, but you can also try to move the function into a trigger (I know, please do not hurt me!). Maybe in this case it can be justified. But you aproach is also correct. If they are not concurrent queries, then it should work well.

Comment: Are you saying that 2k rows per minute are written to the DB that you need to process? Do you have any control over how they are recieved? Im not sure i understand the scenario, but could you convert the coordinates to a cartesian coordinate system, and write that to the DB? Those point distance queries could possibly be faster

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the reported times could be the actual cpu time for the process or could be the elapsed real time. but anyway if it took about half time (real) for you to finish the job when you ran two queries in parallel, you surely had gained efficiency.

Comment: @zedd I have steady stream of multiple avl data sources and are stored in `avl_pool`. Then I have to process each avl `x, y, azimuth` to find the closest road to know where the car is. That is the `near_link` function. Inside the function I use postgis to find the link, and as I said is very fast `8ms` the problem is when number or rows increase the total time also increase.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How should I rewrite the UDF? I just found out 9.6 version has a parallel functionality. Do you think that would help in this case?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Your calculation function is CPU bound. The data retrieval is IO bound. If most of the time is spent on the CPU bound component (8ms) then using a parallel thread count of 2 * CPU Cores + 1 or something similar will give you maximum throughput.

Comment: I don't understand FUNCTION map.get_near_link(). But the number LIMIT 101 seems a bit arbitrary. Would changing it to half, 11 or just 1 give you the same result with faster execution?

Comment: @KjetilS. That function use `<->` operator to find the closest geometric object to the point.  For some weird bug doesnt return the result in order. So I bring the 101 rows using the operator, then sort for distance and choose the closest one. But as I say the function is already very fast 8ms for each row.

Comment: Don't know about Postgresql, but Sql Server will automatically run a query in parallel in situations where it can help.

Comment: Thanks @JoelCoehoorn I will check with Sql Server. Right now I solve it with a C# app using `Parallel.For()` and split the query by ranges.

Answer (score 2):

Consider marking your `map.get_near_link` function as [`PARALLEL SAFE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createfunction.html). This will tell the database engine that it is allowed to try generate a parallel plan when executing the function:

> PARALLEL UNSAFE indicates that the function can't be executed in
>   parallel mode and the presence of such a function in an SQL statement
>   forces a serial execution plan. This is the default. PARALLEL
>   RESTRICTED indicates that the function can be executed in parallel
>   mode, but the execution is restricted to parallel group leader.
>   PARALLEL SAFE indicates that the function is safe to run in parallel
>   mode without restriction.

There are several settings which can cause the query planner not to generate a parallel query plan under any circumstances. Consider this documentation:

- [15.4. Parallel Safety](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/parallel-safety.html)
- [15.2. When Can Parallel Query Be Used?](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html)

On my reading, you may be able to achieve a parallel plan if you refactor your function like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION map.get_near_link(
    x NUMERIC,
    y NUMERIC,
    azim NUMERIC)
RETURNS TABLE
(Link_ID INTEGER, Distance INTEGER, Sendito TEXT, Geom GEOGRAPHY)
AS
$$
        SELECT 
               S.Link_ID,
               TRUNC(ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT('|| X || ' ' || Y || ')',4326), S.geom) * 100000)::INTEGER AS distance,
               S.sentido,
               v.geom
        FROM (
          SELECT *
          FROM map.vzla_seg
          WHERE ABS(Azim - S.azimuth) NOT BETWEEN 30 AND 330
        ) S
          INNER JOIN map.vzla_rto v
            ON S.link_id = v.link_id
        WHERE
            ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT('|| X || ' ' || Y || ')',4326), S.geom) * 100000 < 50
        ORDER BY
            S.geom <-> ST_GeomFromText('POINT('|| X || ' ' || Y || ')', 4326)
        LIMIT 1
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
PARALLEL SAFE -- Include this parameter
;
```

If the query optimiser will generate a parallel plan when executing this function, you won't need to implement your own parallelisation logic.

Comment: I fail to see what is the main difference on the query to make it parallel safe? Also I dont agree with removing the index_query cte, because reduce the problem to only the 100 link near the point speed the next query a lot.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, I forgot to actually add the `PARALLEL SAFE` parameter keywords; see updated answer. On my reading of documentation (see links in the answer), scans of CTE's yield operations that are parallel restricted.

Answer (score 0):

I have done things like this.  It works relatively well.  Note that each connection can handle exactly one query at a time so for each partition of your query, you have to have a separate connection.  Now, in C# you could use threads to interact with each connection.

But another option would be to use asynchronous queries and have a single thread manage and poll your entire connection pool (this sometimes simplifies data manipulations on the application side).  Note in this case you are best ensuring a sleep or other yield point after every poll cycle.

Note further that the extent to which this speeds the query depends on your disk I/O subsystem and your CPU parallelism.  So you cannot just throw more pieces of a query and expect a speed up.

Comment: Thanks. Im solving this with [**Parallel.For**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902019/can-i-use-parallel-for-with-sql-commands) and yes, one connection for each query. And stop follow me :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with SSIS by creating a script that buckets each server into 7 different "@Mode"  (In my case the many servers assigns @Mode based on the last three digits of their IP -- this creates fairly evenly distributed buckets.

```
 (CONVERT(int, RIGHT(dbserver, 3)) % @stages) + 1 AS Mode
```

In SSIS, I have 7 sets of the same 14 large queries running. Each are assigned a different @Mode number that is passed to the stored procedure.

Essentially this allows for 7 simultaneous queries that never run on the same server and effectively cutting the runtime down by approx 85%.

So, Create an SSIS package with the first step of refreshing the @Mode table.

Then create a container that contains 7 containers.  Within each of those 7 containers execute your SQL queries with Parameter Mapping to @Mode.  I point everything to stored procs, so in my case the SQLStatement field reads something like:  `EXEC StoredProc ?`. The `?` will then check the Parameter Mapping you created for @Mode.

Finally, in the SQL query, be sure that @Mode is indicated as a variable for which server to run the query against.

Comment: Sorry Scott. But I don't understand almost anything of this solution. Not sure how implemented. Also in my case I only have a server with multiple CPU..